# “他们之间不再会有什么友谊”：在这个句子里"会“贡献什么意思？

Tags: translation, meaning

我的问题就对于这个句子：

> 他们之间不再**会**有什么友谊。

我的英语翻译是：

> There can no longer be any friendship between them.

为了了解“会”的贡献，我就试试删除它，后来翻译一下：

> 他们之间不再有什么友谊。

我的英文翻译成为：

> There is no longer any friendship between them.

## “会” 的贡献

消除“会”导致消除将来友谊的可能性。

我的尝试是否合理？ 谢谢。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 消除“会”导致消除将来友谊的可能性。

Yes, your understanding is correct. 会 in the context refers to the future tense. Removed 会,  他们之间不再有什么友谊 doesn't specify the tense and we'd have to rely on context to determine whether it happens in the past, present or future.

Answer (score 1):

Speculation about the future is just that: speculation, someone's opinion.

That 会 I would read as 将会:

他们之间不再将会有什么友谊。
They ain't gonna be friends anymore. (speculation about the future)

To locate the 会less sentence clearly in the past, we could add:

从那时候起，他们之间不再有什么友谊。
Since then there isn't any friendship between them. (ongoing lack of friendship)

Answer (score 0):

会 means will/would.

In Chinese we would usually speak more natively by switching 会 and 再.

他们之间不会再有什么友谊。

他们(they)之间(between)不(no)会(would)再(longer/another)有(have)什么(some/what)友谊(friendship).